# Propagation delay vs. transmission delay

Tags: networking

What's the difference between propagation delay and transmission delay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Propagation delay focuses on speed of signal travel through a medium:  fiber, copper, air, etc.  Transmission delay is overall delay, including delays through equipment as well as media.

Answer (score 0):

**Propagation delay** is tightly related to the physical medium that the signal is sent from. It might be an optic fiber, coaxial cable or a twisted pair copper wire.

**Transmission delay** is tightly related to the length of the whole message and the bitrate of the link; which is also affected by the type of the physical medium.

Though it might be completely two different things at the first glance, they might **affect** each other. Because the actual bitrate of the medium is also dedicated to the type of the physical medium.